# С# поиск bytes в большом файле и замена

Tags: c#, wpf

Надо поменять в 4 местах hex значение в большом файле 6 gb
Использую этот код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public static class BinaryUtility
{
    public static IEnumerable<byte> GetByteStream(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        const int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer;
        do
        {
            buffer = reader.ReadBytes(bufferSize);
            foreach (var d in buffer) { yield return d; }
        } while (bufferSize == buffer.Length);
    }

    public static void Replace(BinaryReader reader, BinaryWriter writer, IEnumerable<Tuple<byte[], byte[]>> searchAndReplace)
    {
        foreach (byte d in Replace(GetByteStream(reader), searchAndReplace)) { writer.Write(d); }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<byte> Replace(IEnumerable<byte> source, IEnumerable<Tuple<byte[], byte[]>> searchAndReplace)
    {
        foreach (var s in searchAndReplace)
        {
            source = Replace(source, s.Item1, s.Item2);
        }
        return source;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<byte> Replace(IEnumerable<byte> input, IEnumerable<byte> from, IEnumerable<byte> to)
    {
        var fromEnumerator = from.GetEnumerator();
        fromEnumerator.MoveNext();
        int match = 0;
        foreach (var data in input)
        {
            if (data == fromEnumerator.Current)
            {
                match++;
                if (fromEnumerator.MoveNext()) { continue; }
                foreach (byte d in to) { yield return d; }
                match = 0;
                fromEnumerator.Reset();
                fromEnumerator.MoveNext();
                continue;
            }
            if (0 != match)
            {
                foreach (byte d in from.Take(match)) { yield return d; }
                match = 0;
                fromEnumerator.Reset();
                fromEnumerator.MoveNext();
            }
            yield return data;
        }
        if (0 != match)
        {
            foreach (byte d in from.Take(match)) { yield return d; }
        }
    }
}

private void FastReplace()
        {
            var byteFastHitPak = File.ReadAllBytes(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\SC\Fast.pak");
            var byteFastHitSig = File.ReadAllBytes(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\SC\Fast.sig");
            var searchAndReplace = new List<Tuple<byte[], byte[]>>()
            {
            Tuple.Create(byteFastHitPak, byteFastHitSig),
            };
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(TexBoxPath.Text + pakchunk0, FileMode.Open)))
            {
                using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(TexBoxPath.Text + pakchunk0 + "1", FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    BinaryUtility.Replace(reader, writer, searchAndReplace);
                }
            }
        }
```

Но он мне не подходит, т.к. файл имеет большой размер + создаётся второй файл что мне тоже не надо. Нужен код который будет быстро искать hex в файле и заменять его. Замена pos не подходит, т.к. файл может меняться

Comment: что значит быстро искать? более чем уверен, что байты внутри не упорядочены, следовательно только линейный поиск с блокировкой файла на время поиска и замены.

Comment: `Нужен код который будет быстро искать hex в файле и заменять его` Нужен код - пишите код. Вопрос то в чем?